# CartoDB / javascript : highlight multipolygon on click

Tags: javascript, cartodb

I have a cartoDB dataset made of around 100 entries (multipolygon geometries) that I retrieve using cartodb.js API.
What is the best way - performancewise- to change the opacity of a given entry (multiplygon) when clicking on the zone ?
I have found [that piece code](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/203433/highlight-polygon-on-click-with-leaflet-) but this implies running a new SQL query and adding a layer each time a polygon is selected which doesn't look optimal.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The layers in cartoDb has an associated css, so you can change this css, whatever you want.

```
 cartodb.createLayer(map, layerSource) 
           .addTo(map)
            .done(function(layer) {

                var layerCartoDBDis = layer.getSubLayer(0);
                var layerCartoDBBa = layer.getSubLayer(1);


    });
             })
             .error(function(err) {
              console.log("error: " + err);
           });     `enter code here`
```

in your javascript

```
            <select id="tipo" >
                <option value="1">layer1</option>
                <option value="2">layer2</option>
            </select>


           $('#tipo').on('change', function(e){
            var capa = $('#tipo').val(); 
            leyenda(capa);
             switch (capa) {
              case "0":                 
                layerCartoDBDis.set('SELECT * FROM demo_DBDis');
                layerCartoDBDis.set('cartocss', '#demo_DBDis{ polygon-fill: #FFFFCC;  polygon-opacity: 0.2;  line-color: #FFF;  line-width: 0.5;  line-opacity: 1;'} );
                break;
               case "1":                    
                layerCartoDBBa.set('SELECT * FROM demo_DBBa');
                layerCartoDBBa.set('cartocss', '#demo_DBBa{ polygon-fill: #FFFFCC;  polygon-opacity: 0.2;  line-color: #FFF;  line-width: 0.5;  line-opacity: 1;'} );
                    break;
}
```